# Get Featured Image from different Model

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have 2 model objects, Business & BusinessImage as so, listed with views and index.html. I am trying to list the business's featured image, but it's not happening. I am getting the following error:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'businessimage_set'

How can I get the business featured image for a list?

**Business**

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=70, default="Business Name")
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField("About", max_length=400)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Categories", blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField("Order", default=0)
    claimed = models.BooleanField("Claimed", default=False)
    featured = models.BooleanField("Featured", default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
        verbose_name = "Business"
        verbose_name_plural = "Businesses"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**BusinessImage**

```
class BusinessImage(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/business")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**view.py**

```
from .models import Business, BusinessImage

def index_view(request):
    latest_business_list = Business.objects.all()
    images = latest_business_list.businessimage_set.all()
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_business_list': latest_business_list,
        'images': images,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

**index.html**

```
{% block content %}

<div class="text-center business_title">
    <h2>Featured</h2>
</div>

{% if latest_business_list %}
{% for business in latest_business_list|slice:":4" %}
{% if business.active %}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    <li><a href="business/{{ business.slug }}/">{{ business.name }}</a></li>
{% for image in latest_business_list.businessimage_set.all %}
        {% if image.featured %}
        <a href="{% url 'single_product' product.slug %}">
            <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{image.image}}" alt="{{image}}">
        </a>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`businessimage_set` is an attribute of a `Business` instance, but you're trying to access it as an attribute of a queryset (i.e. list of businesses). If your goal is just to be able to access the images for each business in a template, you can leave out `images` entirely. Instead your template would have:

```
{% for image in business.businessimage_set.all %}
```

(Though look into `prefetch_related` for efficiency.)